# iOS 10: CoreBluetooth CBCentralManager state is unsupported/unauthorised

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios10, core-bluetooth

We are working on a BLE framework which is based on [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth) framework to connect a peripheral with iOS device. I am having an issue with [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager) state in devices (**to be specific iPhone 6 & iPad Mini 2nd Gen**) running iOS 10.

I toggled BLE from iOS settings multiple times and left the app as in BLE off state for 5-6 hours. Then I turned BLE on from iOS settings and received `CBManagerState Unsupported or Unauthorised` in  `centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)`.

However the expected state was `CBManagerState PoweredOn` as i just turned BLE on. I had to kill the app and re-launch it. Then only I got PoweredOn state. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on with CoreBluetooth stack here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: when you turn on the BLE, does it start searching for other devices, or its state remain unsupported

Comment: @FahadJamal When I turn BLE on, i'll receive centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) delegate callback in which I receive unsupported/unauthorised state.

Comment: Probably a bug. Try to request the state again after receiving the event in a few seconds later.